# Domain Url created during WebView request

Tags: ios, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, uiwebview, app-transport-security

There has been a strange behaviour of the request url's I am getting in `UIWebView`. But the strange behaviour is just for test server url's and not for production url's. Let me state an example :

Production server url request from `UIWebView` :
**Url** : prod.com/About/Index  (Works fine)

Test server url request from `UIWebView` :
**Url** : test.com/About/Index   (Is further redirected to below url)
**Redirected Url** : test://About/Index

I am not at all sure why I am getting the redirected url just on test server, although both production and test servers share common code.
Since I am not exactly able to categorise the issue, I am tagging both mobile and server technologies.

Comment: Are you testing on an iOS 9+ device? If yes, maybe your prod server has a SSL certificate and test server does not have a SSL certificate. In iOS9+ the OS blocks non https requests. Check out "App Transport Security" in iOS.

Comment: @7vikram7 : I have set App Transport security setting (NSAllowsArbitraryLoads) to True.